# How to get product by id and products filtered by attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, database

I have the following code in my **Block/Main.php**:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\TireSearch\Block;
class Main extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    function _prepareLayout(){

        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $product = $collection->load(21704);
        var_dump($product->getData());

        exit;
}
```

By my understanding, this should show the data for the product with id 21704, but I seem to be seeing all the products, along with the query at the beginning:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`array(11821) { [0]=> array(15) { ["entity_id"]=> string(5) "18710" ["attribute_set_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["type_id"]=> string(12) "configurable" ["sku"]=> string(9) "CONTI_DWS" ["has_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["required_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-18 20:42:55" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-18 20:42:55" ["price"]=> string(8) "150.2900" ["tax_class_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["final_price"]=> string(8) "150.2900" ["minimal_price"]=> string(8) "150.2900" ["min_price"]=> string(8) "150.2900" ["max_price"]=> string(8) "150.2900" ["tier_price"]=> NULL } 
[1]=> array(15) { ["entity_id"]=> string(5) "18711" ["attribute_set_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["type_id"]=> string(12) "configurable" ["sku"]=> string(8) "DURATRAC" ["has_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["required_options"]=> string(1) "0" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-18 20:42:55" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2016-05-18 20:42:55" ["price"]=> string(8) "185.9800" ["tax_class_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["final_price"]=> string(8) "185.9800" ["minimal_price"]=> string(8) "185.9800" ["min_price"]=> string(8) "185.9800" ["max_price"]=> string(8) "185.9800" ["tier_price"]=> NULL } ...
```

What am I doing wrong? And If I wanted filter the products by some attribute stored in the database, how would I do that? For example, say there is information about the size (cm) of each of my products in the database, How can I filter the products by this attribute? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Below code for load product by id:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

For add product 
`->addAttributeToFilter()` should works like in `M1` on an `EAV collection` and -`>addFieldToFilter()` on a Flat Collection.

Answer (score 1):

**Get product by id using object manager**

> $productId = "2"; //Product Id
>
> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
>
> $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

```
echo $product->getName()."<br>"; 
echo $product->getPrice()."<br>";
```

**Get Product filter by attribute Example**
Here i am taking filter by sku = Samsung Galaxy M30 , where **Samsung Galaxy M30** is my **sku**.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollection->create()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'Samsung Galaxy M30')
              ->load();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($collection->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use objectManager directly in files as magento 2 ECGM2 coding standard**

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

Comment: Why don't use objectManager?

Comment: As Magento 2 coding standard they don't allow direct use of object instance in class. You can get more info here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117098/magento-2-to-use-or-not-to-use-the-objectmanager-directly